# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm' while calling SAP PI web service

Tags: c#, web-services, sap-pi, sap-xi

I am currently creating a .NET C# service which uses webservice invoking to send information from CRM 2011 to SAP PI.

The credentials are said as following:

```
((BasicHttpBinding)defaultBinding).Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
((BasicHttpBinding)defaultBinding).Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic; //.Ntlm;

PropertyInfo piClientCreds = type.GetProperty("ClientCredentials");
ClientCredentials creds = (ClientCredentials)piClientCreds.GetValue(obj, null);
PropertyInfo piWindowsCreds = creds.GetType().GetProperty("Windows");
WindowsClientCredential windowsCreds = (WindowsClientCredential)piWindowsCreds.GetValue(creds, null);
PropertyInfo piAllowNtlm = windowsCreds.GetType().GetProperty("AllowNtlm");
piAllowNtlm.SetValue(windowsCreds, true, null);
PropertyInfo piCredentials = windowsCreds.GetType().GetProperty("ClientCredential");
piCredentials.SetValue(windowsCreds, credentials, null);
PropertyInfo piImpersonation = windowsCreds.GetType().GetProperty("AllowedImpersonationLevel");
piImpersonation.SetValue(windowsCreds, System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation, null);
```

The error I get is:

> ```
> {System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is
>    unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header
>    received from the server was 'Basic realm="Upload Protected Area"'.
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> ```

Any help in resolving this and if possible making it dynamic is much appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite obvious. The server expects the your client to use Basic authentication while your client attempts to authenticate using NTLM. Try authenticating using [UserNamePasswordClientCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.usernamepasswordclientcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You should do this only over a secure transport such as HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Could you help me out a bit further in translating this web of property's to the correct format?